# Match a string between hash symbols

Tags: regex

I have a string in this shape

`State#Received#ID#e23d8926-1327-4fde-9ea7-d364af3325e0`

I want to extract the State value via RegEx. So in this above example I only want to extract `Received`

I have tried the following `([^State#])([A-Za-z])` which matches `Received` but I am stuck at excluding the rest of the string `#ID#e23d8926-1327-4fde-9ea7-d364af3325e0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use a parenthesis for the group you don't want to capture. My solution is that:

`State#(?'state'[^#]+)#`

Sample: https://regex101.com/r/vAr65j/1